# slowMotion in iphone game based in opengl es

Tags: iphone, performance, opengl-es, motion

I want to implement slow motion in a game, based on opengl.

What I mean is when ball is about to touch the cylinder then it should be displayed in slow motion. I am using opengl es first time. So please help me.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All your game logic should be dependant of the frametime (deltatime) which can be seen the ammount of time for each frame. By making this deltatime larger or shorter you can make things go faster or slower.

For example, moving a point using velocity should be thought this way:

position += velocity*deltatime;

you can change deltatime at will which can produce easily the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable time to my question, but i have explained my answer below.

Thank You.